# How to resolve ssh: not found in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I got stuck in Jenkins Pipeline with ssh command. The error is:

```
+ ssh

/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-docker-jenkins@tmp/durable-2c3c7fb4/script.sh: line 1: ssh: not found

script returned exit code 127
```

My Jenkins File is:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
      docker {
        image 'node:15.12.0-alpine'
      }
    }
    stages {
      stage("Prepare") {
          steps {
            sh "yarn"
          }
      }
      stage("Build") {
          steps {
            sh "yarn build"
          }
      }
      stage("Deploy") {
        steps {
          sh "ssh"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem? Or is there anyway ssh to remote server in Jenkins Pipeline? Thank in advance. Have a good day!

Comment: You are trying to ssh from a docker container of image `node:15.12.0-alpine` and it doesn't contain ssh.   From Jenkins, you can of course do SSH https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/

Comment: Ok I got it. If I want to use ssh, I have to get ssh package. Is is right? I mean ssh package in docker. Thank a lot!

Comment: Right. I will post the above comment as an answer for better visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to ssh from a docker container of image `node:15.12.0-alpine` and it doesn't contain `ssh`. From Jenkins, you can of course do SSH here is the SSH plugin of Jenkins and relevant documentation. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/